# Не видна переменная NAN javascript OOP

Tags: javascript, ооп

```
function UserSubscribes(){ 
this.count = 0;
    this.CreateSocketsAccept = function(eventNameListen){
     var self = this;  
         self.PrepareToHTMLdata(data); 
     this.count++;

            });
        }
},

this.PrepareToHTMLdata = function(){

        console.log(this.count);// выводит NaN
}

}
```

Было бы хорошо, чтобы я уяснил эту проблему, потому как второй вопрос уже схожий с этим..

Comment: вы что-то не то делаете :) объявите self вообще в UserSubscribes, вот так:

    function UserSubscribes(){   
       var self=this; 
     //....

там теория такая - есть контест функции (this) и scope(объявления в замыканиях) scope лексическая, а контекст логический, например в браузере - `function a() {var a=1;setTimeout(funct,10);}a();` в funct в scope будет входить глобальный и область видимости функции `a`  а контекст - окно, т.к. это событие вызванное окном. чтобы обойти это можно **текущий** контекст запомнить в области видимости и потом оттуда взять.

Comment: чтобы окончательно понять поместите console.log(this) в разные методы вашего объекта

Comment: Spasibo, uje 4to-to yasno. A esli tak var c = new UserSubscribes();
alert(c.count); Почему не видно переменной?

Comment: что-то не то делаете в простейшем случае всё работает. http://jsfiddle.net/Nhk7Y/

Comment: Благодарю - все работает